# Trigger.Once with Azure Event Hubs

Tags: spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

I was reading about using Streaming with Trigger.Once instead of batch processing (https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/22/running-streaming-jobs-day-10x-cost-savings.html). I'm using Azure Event Hubs as a source, which has a 10.000 items limit per trigger and I have to process a few million events. This will result in processing only 10.000 items and the stream stops when you enable Trigger.Once. Has anyone any idea on how to do this with streaming and Trigger.Once like functionality and stop when the stream is empty or processed up until a set time?

Comment: I have the same question!

Answer (score 0):

Recently got chance implement something similar:

**Our need was;**

1. Hourly once the Databricks will launch a job and reads from last ran offset of eventhub
2. Persist the data on to location
3. end the job and cluster goes back to idle/termination mode

This is how we achieved it:

**Set eventhub conf:**

```
val eventHubsConf: EventHubsConf = EventHubsConf(connStr).setMaxEventsPerTrigger(<someNumber>).setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromOffset("@latest"))
```

**Read from eventhub:**

```
val incomingStream = spark.readStream.format("<your_evenhub_name>").options(eventHubsConf.toMap).load()
```

**Write with Trigger.Once**

```
incomingStream.writeStream
  .format("parquet").outputMode("append").trigger(Trigger.Once())
  .partitionBy("<yourpartitionColumn>").option("truncate", false)
  .option("checkpointLocation", "<yourcheckpointlocation>")
  .option("path", "<youroutputdataDir>")
  .start()
```